# Json dynamic data doesn't work from Jquery response

Tags: jquery, json

this is the code working here http://jsfiddle.net/gR2y4/

but when I try this doesn't work.

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "xx.aspx" }).done(function (response) {
var resp = response;
alert(resp._TypingUserList[0].UserNick);
});
```

thanks for your effort.

Comment: what is there in your response. json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax call needed return datatype as json,

adding datatype fixed the problem.

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",dataType: "json", url: "xx.aspx" }).done(function (response) {
var resp = response;
alert(resp._TypingUserList[0].UserNick);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual data is in `response.d` It's the way ASP.NET responds to your AJAX call. See [this link](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/)

Comment: adding dataType: "json" fixed my problem. thanks for your effort anyway :)